# node.js require returns a string instead of module object

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to make an **electron** app. However, my work stuck on very beginning: the `require` keyword gives me a string, instead of module object.

```
electron = require('electron')
console.log(electron)
```

It prints:

```
/path/to/my/project/node_modules/_electron@1.6.11@electron/dist/electron
```

, that totally cannot be used as a module.

In comparison, if I import a built-in module, or another npm-installed module:

```
fs = require('fs')
console.log(fs)

mkdirp = require('mkdirp')
console.log(mkdirp)
```

It prints object hierarchy, including variables and functions.

The following are contents of election directory, I don't know if they are healthy:

```
$ ls node_modules/electron
appveyor.yml  cli.js  CONTRIBUTING.md  dist  electron.d.ts  index.js  install.js  issue_template.md  LICENSE  node_modules  package.json  path.txt  README.md  test
```

Comment: can you do var fs = require('fs'); and in console you get all the function . if you want to use function from fs then make sure use function name like 

fs.readFile();

Comment: try to follow the following link you will get the right way:- > https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. You need to run your app using electron (in node_modules/.bin), not plain node.

This is what the [official tutorial](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app) uses inside package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron ."
}
```

This ends up calling the [electron cli](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/9dfb85dd21bed39639144e30f3438debdf9010d2/npm/cli.js), which uses `require` to [find the path to electron.exe](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/9dfb85dd21bed39639144e30f3438debdf9010d2/npm/index.js) (the string you discovered) and spawns that as a child process that runs the app.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron#readme) it should be possible to `require('electron')` to access objects like `app`, `BrowserWindow`and `remote`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @Marc. The readme you linked to says: "Most people use Electron from the command line, but if you require `electron` inside your **Node app** (not your Electron app) it will return the file path to the binary." In other words, if you `require('electron')` from Node instead of Electron, you will just get a string.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Electron app". Electron is just a runtime for node - so my node app IS my electron app.

Comment: Yeah, the terminology is a little odd. There's a different executable when you use Electron. You don't use node.exe; you use electron.exe. So if you run `node index.js` (and index.js has the require), that will just get you a string. If you were to run `electron index.js`, it will give you the objects that you expect. But that's not the exact command to use because the electron executable is somewhere inside `node_modules`, which is why it's recommended to use the start script that I copied above (so you can use `npm run start` to run it).

Comment: OK, I'm doing `require` inside a renderer process of an app started with `electron .`. The `require` function is unknown and I've had to inject it via a preload script.

Comment: Ah, that's a very different problem than what this question here is about. That's probably related to `nodeIntegration`. In [Node version 5](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content), they started setting `nodeIntegration` to `false` by default on the [BrowserWindow's webPreferences](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions). Most of the examples in the documentation assume that you have `nodeIntegration` set to true.

Comment: I have the new equivalent of `nodeIntegration: true` which is `contextIsolation: false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226566/discussion-between-andrew-myers-and-marc).